# TSQL - How can I get the total count in a group as part of a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vistadb

I need to get the total calls per hour per user for the current day, and then calculate the percentage of incoming calls taken by that user.  The purpose in the final analysis is to calculate the percentage of a bonus pot per user per hour.

I can get most of the bits, but am stuck calculating the total calls per hour i.e. total calls for each hour group...

Assume the following data (change the date to the current date if necessary):

```
EnteredBy           EnteredOn
Lisa Scandaleyes    05/07/2017 07:40:04
Fred Smith          05/07/2017 07:54:17
A User              05/07/2017 08:15:06
Johnny Johnson      05/07/2017 08:20:57
A User              05/07/2017 09:27:29
A User              05/07/2017 09:36:16
A User              05/07/2017 09:42:36
A User              05/07/2017 10:09:57
```

I can easily get the calls per hour:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn]) AS Hour, Count(*) as CallsPerHour
FROM CallHandlingCallData 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, EnteredOn, GetDate())= 0 
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn])
ORDER BY Hour;
```

I can also get the calls per hour per user:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn]) AS Hour, EnteredBy, Count(*) as CallsTaken
FROM CallHandlingCallData 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d,EnteredOn, GetDate())= 0
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn]), EnteredBy
ORDER BY Hour, EnteredBy;
```

I can even get almost everything I want EXCEPT that the TotalCalls value and therefore the percentage is based on ALL CALLS for the day:

```
SELECT Hour, EnteredBy, CallsTaken, TotalCalls, 
CAST(CallsTaken AS Decimal(10,2)) * 100 / CASE TOTALCALLS WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE TotalCalls END AS Percentage 
FROM
(
    SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn]) AS Hour, EnteredBy, Count(*)as CallsTaken, 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM CallHandlingCallData WHERE DATEDIFF(d, EnteredOn, GetDate())= 0) AS TotalCalls
    FROM CallHandlingCallData
    WHERE DATEDIFF(d,EnteredOn, GetDate())= 0
    GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn]), EnteredBy
) data
ORDER BY Hour, EnteredBy;
```

This is really close, I just need to get the sub-query to give me the total calls for that hour, instead of for the whole day.

*Notes*

1. *I am unable to use OVER() as it is not supported by one of the database engines that may be used with the final query.*
2. *I would prefer to do such calculations in the UI, but the result has to be output to a spreadsheet removing that option*

Any suggestions would be most gratefully received.

Comment: What do you mean `not supported by one of the database engines`? Which versions are you targeting? Note that the earliest *supported* SQL Server version is 2012

Comment: `OVER` would make your life  whole lot easier, it's supported since 2005. `COUNT(*) OVER (Partition By DATEPART(HOUR, [EnteredOn]))`

Comment: VistaDB is one of the engines in use, and it does not support OVER(). I understand that SQLite does not either... SQL Server 2012 - 2016 is used for the bigger customers, but smaller businesses may use an older version or an alternative engine.

Comment: Does VistaDB support `CROSS APPLY`? That would allow an alternate solution without `OVER` -- just `CROSS APPLY` to select the total number of calls in that hour. Heck, you can even get away with a `JOIN` on a subquery in this case.

Comment: Cross Apply, no.  Join, not a problem.  Can you suggest a solution with a join please?  My brain seems to have gone numb :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the group totals separately, then join them up.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(HOUR, C1.EnteredOn) AS [Hour], 
    C1.EnteredBy, 
    COUNT(*) AS CallsTaken, 
    Totals.TotalCalls, 
    CAST(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / Totals.TotalCalls AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS [Percentage]
FROM CallHandlingCallData AS C1
JOIN (
    SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, C2.EnteredOn) AS [Hour], COUNT(*) AS TotalCalls
    FROM CallHandlingCallData AS C2
    WHERE DATEDIFF(d, C2.EnteredOn, GetDate()) = 0
    GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, C2.EnteredOn)
) Totals ON Totals.[Hour] = DATEPART(HOUR, C1.EnteredOn) 
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, C1.EnteredOn, GetDate()) = 0
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR, C1.EnteredOn), 
    C1.EnteredBy, 
    Totals.TotalCalls
```

If it looks like I'm overdoing it with the aliases: I find it's much better to be safe than sorry when it comes to disambiguating inner and outer column references.

If you need rows with zeroes for hours where nothing happened as well, that's a whole 'nother kettle of fish with `UNION ALL` and number tables and I'm not going there unless we have to.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks.  All I had to do was add an ORDER BY clause to put the hours together and sort by EnteredOn to give the perfect result...

There is no way I would have thought to do it like you did, thanks for the lesson!